# (Beginner) How to call Outlook RESTful APIs in Outlook VSTO Add-In

Tags: vsto, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

I'm looking to develop an Outlook Add-In, in which I receive a meeting room request and propose another room based upon conditions relating number of participants and size of the other rooms. I'm attempting to do this using a VSTO Add-In in C#.

My problem comes in the algorithm to determine the list of rooms and which room is smaller. From research, I can see that Outlook incorporates a number of RESTful APIs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations). However, I'm running into roadblocks in terms of how to call the APIs and how to get their data.

Is this possible in a VSTO add-in? If so, how could I get and store a list of the meeting rooms in Outlook using the REST APIs? I know there are other types of add-ins but I'm unfamiliar with Javascript and thus I'd like to stay with C#.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using the [web add-in framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/), instead of COM, for writing an Outlook add-in. The web add-in framework enables developers to:

1. Write once and have their add-in run across supported Outlook
   clients enabling the add-in to reach millions of Outlook Desktop,
   Outlook for Web, Outlook for Mac, and Outlook Mobile users.
2. Simplified deployment through the Office store, enabling users to acquire your add-in with a single click.
3. Access to user mailbox data via a rich REST based API set.

In addition to the benefits of the web add-in framework, Microsoft is *not* investing in new functionality on the COM platform. We understand COM add-ins may support different scenarios than the web add-in framework and thus are continually investing in the web add-in framework.

If you have any feedback or new functionality you would like to see available in the web add-in framework please let us know.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](//officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]