# Do I need to develop multiple versions of my MS Outlook VSTO add-in?

Tags: vsto

I am about to develop my first ever MS Outlook add-in (following [this MS guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx)).

As I create my new project, I see this ...

[image]

Was there really such a change between these versions of Outlook? Does this mean that I will have two develop two copies of my add-in? Is there no forward/backward comparability?

---

Am I even following the correct guide? Should I be developing a VSTO? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521086/beginner-how-to-call-outlook-restful-apis-in-outlook-vsto-add-in) has an answer by `Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT` (although their profile does not actually any actual MS affiliation), which starts

> We recommend using the [web add-in framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/), instead of COM, for
>   writing an Outlook add-in. The web add-in framework enables developers
>   to:
>
> Write once and have their add-in run across supported Outlook clients
>   enabling the add-in to reach millions of Outlook Desktop, Outlook for
>   Web, Outlook for Mac, and Outlook Mobile users.

Comment: FYI, I have a few examples of VSTO projects in GitHub https://github.com/Office-projects.

Comment: Great. That will give me something to study, and maybe use as a base.

Comment: I am busy reading [Comparing VSTO and Office Web add-ins](http://techgenix.com/comparing-vsto-and-office-web-add-ins-video/), and maybe a few more, to help me decide which path to take for development - the probably quicker, currently more popular (with more examples) VSTO, or the newer, cross-platofrm (think smartphones) web add-in. Any advice?

Comment: I've just started getting into development with the web Addins. If you're good with JavaScript it may be the way to go.

Comment: MSDN has a few examples of the web Addins as well as Microsoft's GitHub repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, a 2013-2016 VSTO Addin will work with 2010. If you need it to work with Office 2007 you'll have to add the assembly [Outlook 2007 Primary Interop Assembly (PIA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb646840(v=office.12).aspx).